# Connecting my laptop to two monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, dell-inspiron

How can I connect my laptop to two monitors, having just one HDMI interface? I have a `Dell Inspiron 14z`.

I have also heard that not every laptop supports 2+ monitors. How can I know that my laptop supports it?

Comment: Look at how many display connectors your laptop has, that's how many monitors you'll be able to connect.

Comment: where can I check that out?

Comment: On the [manufacturer's page](http://www.dell.com/us/dfh/p/inspiron-14z/pd) or just by looking at the laptop for display ports (DisplayPort, VGA port or HDMI port).

Comment: So I have 1 HDMI port --> I can just connect to 1 monitor. Are there any ways that i can use some kind of a splitter so that i can use extend my desktop to to 3 monitors (1 the original laptop and 2 external monitors)